# Autoencoder for dimensionality reduction of binary dataset for clustering

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

Given a binary dataset (derived from yes/no questionnaire responses) aimed to use for subsequent unsupervised cluster analysis, with significant multicolinearity and a total of 31 features by ~50,000 observations (subjects), it appeared sensible to reduce the dimensionality of the input data before performing cluster analysis. I attempted using an autoencoder for this, but surprisingly, the clusters (derived through k-medoids, chosen due to the nominal nature of the underlying data and a greater stability in relation to outliers/noise compared to e.g., k-means) were actually more distinct and clearly distinguished when using MCA, with a clear maximum Silhouette coefficient at k = 5.

Given that MCA with the first 5 PCs (explaining just ~75% of the variance, chosen through a scree plot) was used before I attempted the autoencoder way, it surprises me that an autoencoder did a worse job at extracting meaningful features at the same bottleneck dimension. **The problem with the current autoencoder, appears to be that the data in the bottleneck layer, which is used in the clustering, is distorted...**

Below is the code I used to construct the autoencoder. Can it be so that the hyper-parameters are off, or some details of the overall architecture? Random search of specific numbers of the number of layers, learning rate, batch size, dimensions in the layers etc. have not yielded anything substantial. Loss is similar between train and validation dataset, and levels out at around 0.15 after ~40 epochs.

I've also tried to identify studies where such data has been used, but not found anything useful.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


input_dim = 31
layer_1_dim = 18
layer_2_dim = 10
bottleneck_dim = 5
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 100
batch_size = 300


# split data into training and validation
training_n = int(data.shape[0] * 0.8)
train_data = data[:training_n, :]
val_data = data[training_n:, :]

# define autoencoder initializer
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()

# autoencoder layers
input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
layer = Dense(layer_1_dim, activation='relu')(input_layer)
layer = Dense(layer_2_dim, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(layer)
layer = Dense(bottleneck_dim, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer, name="bottleneck-output")(layer)
layer = Dense(layer_2_dim, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(layer) 
layer = Dense(layer_1_dim, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(layer)
output_layer = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer)(layer)

# define and compile autoencoder model
autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')

# train the autoencoder model
history = autoencoder.fit(train_data, train_data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(val_data, val_data))

# get bottleneck output
bottleneck_autoencoder = Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('bottleneck-output').output)
bottleneck_output = bottleneck_autoencoder.predict(data)

# plot loss in traning and validation set
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Autoencoder loss (binary cross-entropy)')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('output/embedding.png')
```

Comment: Autoencoders use to struggle when a lot of multicolinearity is present betwen the features of the input data, as it can lead to unstable representations in the bottleneck layer. You need to reduce multicolinearity for example, using the principal component analysis (PCA) method before feeding the data into the autoencoder.

Comment: @kithuto thank you for this information; it sounds reasonable. If running e.g., MCA prior to autoencoder, given the relatively low dimensionality in the data, what degree of dimensions do you reckon one should keep?

Comment: If I had to do it I just test with diferent numbers of features taking the ones with less multicollinearity and comparing the results (changing the autoencoder too). I can't give you an exact answer it really depends on your data. Just create or search for a library to compare diferent aproaches to find out whats is the best option for you. Make sure to not overfit or underfit the data.

Comment: What do you mean by distorted?

You can try using a sigmoid as opposed to relu in the bottleneck layer, or even in all of the layers without worrying too much about vanishing gradient, because the autoencoder is using Glorot weight initialization and is relatively "shallow".

Sigmoid will keep output values bounded (0,1) as opposed to relu which is (0,inf), which you may want if you are using the bottleneck layer outputs as inputs for clustering.

If training is slow, you could also try tanh (-1,1) which will produce a larger gradient than sigmoid when training.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem with multicollinearity is that, on top of not allowing for meaningful inference, it hamper your convergence rate.
This implies that, everything equal, if your data is highly multicollinear you need significantly more data to achieve convergence.

According to what your objective is (pure prediction vs. inference) you might want to either orthogonalize (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)) your input and then feed the residuals to your autoencoder or you might want to choose a more sensible activation function or go with a sparse autoencoder.

That said, I would suggest to try the last two steps first if you are aiming to have good predictions and do not necessarily care about inference:

1. change your activation function in the bottleneck (use a Sigmoid?).
2. use a sparse autoencoder see [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Sparse_autoencoder_(SAE)) and [here](https://medium.com/@syoya/what-happens-in-sparse-autencoder-b9a5a69da5c6)

Comment: Thank you for this; seems sensible. What's the theoretical background for sigmoid being better suited here? And should the other layers remain with ReLU activation? Also, does e.g., logistic PCA fall under the category of orthogonalization as well?

Comment: The sigmoid was just a suggestion as it is a "well behaved" class of functions. You know that its support is bounded and the first derivative will be gaussian shaped (hence also the gradient is "well behaved").
My point was more about the fact that ReLU is unbounded, while I understand from your question that your training vectors (categorical variables being the answers in a questionnaire) do not have arbitrarily large values or are in any way unbounded. This makes the use of ReLU as activation function not a great candidate in this instance

Comment: Many thanks! The orthogonalization methods... is PCA/MCA one of them? And should one retain 100% of variance, or would that mess up the data?

Answer (score 1):

Since the main problem here is multicollinearity, you can try using a dimensionality reduction method that factors in non-linear relationships within the data. One common example is [kernelPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis#:%7E:text=In%20the%20field%20of%20multivariate,a%20reproducing%20kernel%20Hilbert%20space.)
Then you can explore different kernel functions, I've usually had interesting results with just linear kernel.